# How to return multi value in UITableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath function in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In Objective-C,

```
 - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete | UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
}
```

this work,
How can i convert to Swift?

Comment: What you are doing isn't valid. `UITableViewCellEditingStyle` is an enum. It is not a bit mask. You are only supposed to return a single value. Besides, what does it mean that a row should show both the green + and the red - icon in the same location to the left of the cell?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return [.Delete, .Insert]
}
```